# Find duplicates in MS SQL table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I know that this question has been asked several times but I still cannot figure out why my query is returning values which are not duplicates. I want my query to return only the records which have identical value in the column `Credit`. The query executes without any errors but values which are not duplicated are also being returned. This is my query:

```
Select
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.AccountDesc,
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.TxDate,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.UserName
From
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial Inner Join
  _bvGLTransactionsFull On _bvGLAccountsFinancial.AccountLink =
    _bvGLTransactionsFull.AccountLink
Where
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit 

IN   
  (SELECT Credit AS NumOccurrences
FROM  _bvGLTransactionsFull
GROUP BY Credit
HAVING (COUNT(Credit) > 1 ) )


Group By
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.AccountDesc, _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.TxDate, _bvGLTransactionsFull.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit, _bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.UserName, _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Master_Sub_Account,
  IsNumeric(_bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference), _bvGLTransactionsFull.TrCode
Having
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.TxDate > 01 / 11 / 2014 And
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference Like '5_____' And
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit > 0.01 And
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Master_Sub_Account = '90210'
```

Comment: But, do you have this duplicate data? Also, are you sure your `HAVING` conditions from your outer query are not filtering the data? I think that running the entire query up to the out-most `GROUP BY` will definitely return what you want (*if the appropriate data is there*).

Answer (score 0):

That's because you're matching on the credit field back to your table, which contains duplicates. You need to isolate the rows that are duplicated with ROW_NUMBER:

```
;WITH CTE AS (
SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY CREDIT ORDER BY (SELECT NULL)) AS RN
FROM _bvGLTransactionsFull)
Select
  CTE.AccountDesc,
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Description,
  CTE.TxDate,
  CTE.Description,
  CTE.Credit,
  CTE.Reference,
  CTE.UserName
From
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial Inner Join
  CTE On _bvGLAccountsFinancial.AccountLink = CTE.AccountLink
WHERE CTE.RN > 1
Group By
  CTE.AccountDesc, _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Description,
  CTE.TxDate, CTE.Description,
  CTE.Credit, CTE.Reference,
  CTE.UserName, _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Master_Sub_Account,
  IsNumeric(CTE.Reference), CTE.TrCode
Having
  CTE.TxDate > 01 / 11 / 2014 And
  CTE.Reference Like '5_____' And
  CTE.Credit > 0.01 And
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Master_Sub_Account = '90210'
```

Just as a side note, I would consider using aliases to shorten your queries and make them more readable. Prefixing the table name before each column in a join is very difficult to read.

Comment: You are actually filtering rows, if you get credits that have duplicate values in `Credit` column, you are **always filtering the first row** of duplicates. So, if he'd have 2 duplicate `Credit` amounts, he would still see one.

Comment: Isolate/filter, we all have our own pedantic terms for the same thing.

Comment: He wants the duplicate rows, not the first rows of each credit. So it makes sense to drop that first row.

Comment: I meant that you are not isolation/filtering, you are removing (excluding from the result set rows which the OP will want to see).

Comment: Where does he say that? I know English is not my native language, but OP never said that.

Answer (score 0):

I trust your code in terms of extracting all data per your criteria. With this, let me have a different approach and see your script "as-is". So then, lets keep first all the records in a temp.

```
Select
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.AccountDesc,
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.TxDate,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.UserName
-- temp table
INTO #tmpTable
From
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial Inner Join
  _bvGLTransactionsFull On _bvGLAccountsFinancial.AccountLink =
    _bvGLTransactionsFull.AccountLink
Where
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit 

IN   
  (SELECT Credit AS NumOccurrences
FROM  _bvGLTransactionsFull
GROUP BY Credit
HAVING (COUNT(Credit) > 1 ) )


Group By
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.AccountDesc, _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.TxDate, _bvGLTransactionsFull.Description,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit, _bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference,
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.UserName, _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Master_Sub_Account,
  IsNumeric(_bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference), _bvGLTransactionsFull.TrCode
Having
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.TxDate > 01 / 11 / 2014 And
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Reference Like '5_____' And
  _bvGLTransactionsFull.Credit > 0.01 And
  _bvGLAccountsFinancial.Master_Sub_Account = '90210'
```

Then remove the "single occurrence" data by creating a row index and remove all those 1 time indexes.

```
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT
  ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Credit ORDER BY Credit) AS rowIdx
  , *
FROM #tmpTable) AS innerTmp
WHERE
  rowIdx != 1
```

You can change your preference through `PARTITION BY <column name>`.
Should you have any concerns, please raise it first as these are so far how I understood your case.

EDIT : To include those credits that has duplicates.

```
SELECT 
    tmp1.*
FROM #tmpTable tmp1
RIGHT JOIN (
       SELECT 
           Credit 
       FROM (
           SELECT
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY Credit ORDER BY Credit) AS rowIdx
              , *
           FROM #tmpTable) AS innerTmp
           WHERE
              rowIdx != 1
       ) AS tmp2
 ON tmp1.Credit = tmp2.Credit
```

Comment: Your query is working perfectly well - however, sorry if my question was not clear enough but I still want the other occurence(s) of the duplicate entry to show. For example if I have two records with Credit of 10.00 I need to see both the records.

Comment: That makes sense, please see my edit. We should be able to right join (right table over the left) to filter out the duplicate credits only.